# Error in opencv_video when compiling ROS Hydro from source in Odroid-U3

Tags: opencv, ros, odroid

I'm having a problem when trying to compile ROS Hydro from the source on Odroid-U3. This is the related error:

```
Built target pch_Generate_opencv_superres
[ 31%] Built target opencv_core
[ 32%] Built target opencv_flann
[ 35%] Built target opencv_ml
[ 42%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 42%] Built target opencv_photo
[ 45%] Built target opencv_video
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(videodsp_armv5te.o): In function `ff_prefetch_arm':
/home/odroid/odroid-sources/sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/videodsp_armv5te.S:29:(.text+0x8): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_THM_JUMP19 against symbol `ff_prefetch_arm' defined in .text section in /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(videodsp_armv5te.o)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.6] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'opencv2': 
  Command '/home/odroid/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/odroid/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv2 && /home/odroid/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

Already tried to install those libraries by `sudo apt-get install` but no difference. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried installing ros from the armhf repo?http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM

Comment: @ZoltanFedor I need some packages that are not in armhf repo. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I understand. I have ordered my Odroid-U3 a few days ago and planning to install ROS on it, but after successfully installing it on Raspberry from source I will probably install it from the armhf repo except if I find a good reason not to.

Comment: I have got my Odroid-U3 and installed ROS Hydro on it from source after installing ffmpeg and opencv. I also compiled the vision_opencv libraries with no problem. I would suggest you compile the standalone opencv, as the one packaged with ROS is an old version based on http://wiki.ros.org/opencv2